# How to decrypt sd card from broken phone?

Tags: encryption, sd-card

Ok this wasn't the brightest thing in the world to do. I encrypted my SD card on my old phone. I bought a new phone, returned my old one to factory settings before I decrypted my SD card. I have the key that I used to encrypt it but I can't decrypt it on either the old phone or the new one. What do I do?

The phone that I have is a Note 4 not encrypted Running version 4.4.4. I encrypted the SD card and the phone on a Note 3 running version 4.4.2 with the same key. I removed the encryption off of the Note 3 (phone) and returned it to factory settings. It does not allow me to de-encrypt the SD card that was in it. It doesn't recognize that the SD card is encrypted. So all of those files are inaccessible. Is there a way that I can de-encrypt the SD card without formatting it and losing all of the data?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read your question again and see if there is enough information to answer it. What phone/platform/version/encryption are we talking about here? Please edit it to include the missing information. Furthermore, this is not a programming question and therefore off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: The phone that I have is a Note 4 not encrypted Running version 4.4.4. I encrypted the SD card and the phone on a Note 3 running version 4.4.2 with the same key. I removed the encryption off of the Note 3 (phone) and returned it to factory settings. It does not allow me to de-encrypt the SD card that was in it. It doesn't recognize that the SD card is encrypted. So all of those files are inaccessible. Is there a way that I can de-encrypt the SD card without formatting it and losing all of the data?